# Google oauth with fastapi-users procedure

Tags: python, google-oauth, fastapi, fastapiusers

I have the first steps working for `fastapi-users==12.0.0` with Google OAuth but I don't know what to do with the `access_token` once I get it from `/auth/google/callback`.

The `fastapi` logs show `User <user_id> has registered` and a new row is added into each table (`user`, `oauth_account`), so that's good.

So far I have:

1. `GET /auth/google/authorize` which returns a JSON with an `authorization_url`.
2. I navigate to that `authorization_url` and authenticate via the prompts at `https://accounts.google.com/signin`.
3. I am redirected to `/auth/google/callback?state=<some_token>&scope=<email, profile, user scopes>=0&prompt=consent`, which shows `{"access_token":<access_token>,"token_type":"bearer"}`.

What am I supposed to do with that `access_token`? To access private endpoints do I need to include it in the header of every future request?

For this strictly google process, do I need to use any of the other endpoints (eg. `/auth/jwt/login`, `/auth/register`, `/auth/request-verify-token`, `/auth/verify`)?

How would I complete this process via the swagger docs? The Authorize form (`OAuth2PasswordBearer`) currently shows `Token URL: auth/jwt/login` and `Flow: password`). I don't need to change that at all right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I supposed to do with that access_token? To access private endpoints do I need to include it in the header of every future request?

Yes. You'll need to include it as authorization header to access your protected resources (the ones that need authorization).

> For this strictly google process, do I need to use any of the other endpoints (eg. /auth/jwt/login, /auth/register, /auth/request-verify-token, /auth/verify)?

These endpoints are not used in Google Oauth flow. This is for normal login using credentials i.e. Username and Password. The endpoint `/auth/jwt/login/` takes your credentials and responds with JWT token similar to what you're going to receive from the `/auth/google/callback`. Now you'll need to store this token in your frontend client or any other service that is calling your endpoint since JWTs are not stored in backend server.